# FTP / WPUT, any simple working solutions?

Tags: bash, ftp, automation, ip-address

Apologies I know this is a well covered question, but I cant seem to find any simple solutions...

Trying to get a problem sorted out and im hoping that somone will be able to assist.

Im creating a script and the only way I can think of to resolve this particular problem is by FTP'ing a file to a remote web server.

.sh script, I tried FTP initially but there appears to be a problem with doing this to do with passwords, I tried a couple of workarounds but this didnt work.

I have then tried wput but that seems to fail as well.

```
#!/bin/sh
wput -v file.php ftp://usr:pass@host.co.uk/docroot/

 bash wput.sh
wput.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
--12:20:58-- `/file.php'
    => ftp://user:xxxxx@host.co.uk/docroot/
Connecting to host.co.uk:21... connected!
Logging in as user ... Logged in!
==> CWD docroot
==> TYPE I ... done.
 ... failed.
==> SYST ... done (UNIX Type: L8).
==> PASV ... done.
==> TYPE A ... done.
==> LIST ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.
==> PASV ... done.
' not understood) Skipping this file
FINISHED --12:20:59--
Transmission of 1 file failed.
wput.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
wput.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
```

Is anyone able to tell me where I'm going wrong. Could this be a file permissions issue or something?

All I need is the simplist solution for transfering a file from my computer to some web space automatically in the simpist way possible.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to run `wput -v file.php ftp://usr:pass@host.co.uk/docroot/` alone, in a shell? Also, are you using Windows?

Comment: I strongly suspect the windows file EOL problem after seeing the '\r'.

Comment: Not using windows, the machine im using is UBUNTU [Linux]. Strangely enough it works if the file does not exist on another webhost. But then skips again once it is there. I presume I need to force it to overwrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ncftpput`:

Examples showing in `ncftpput` help menu:

```
  ncftpput -u gleason -p my.password Elwood.probe.net /home/gleason stuff.txt
  ncftpput -u gleason Elwood.probe.net /home/gleason a.txt (prompt for pass)
  ncftpput -a -u gleason -p my.password -m -U 007 Bozo.probe.net /tmp/tmpdir a.txt
  tar cvf - /home | ncftpput -u operator -c Server.probe.net /backups/monday.tar
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package ncftpput
This is ubuntu linux btw ahh looks like you meant ncftp?

Comment: This worked like a charm `ncftpput -u user -p pass webspace.co.uk /remotefiletostorein/ /local/file/tostore.php`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is interested here is the finished script. All it does is connect to a simple php script to determine my remote IP. (This is done by a cron job every few mins). It compares the IP it finds to a file where it stored the IP address last time. If its changed it saves the IP in the comparison file "file1.txt" and FTP's the file up to ISP hosted webspace. The plan being I can then use the IP as a variable in redirecting pages or just to check my most recent IP.

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Check IP address compare to see if its changed.
# Save the file to a couple of different places locally
# FTP the file to regular hosting.
# File to keep IP address in
IP_FILE=file1.txt
echo "File to store and compare IP:" $IP_FILE
# wget to check current IP address.
IPADDRESS=$(wget URL/ip.php -O - -q)
echo "New IP:" $IPADDRESS
# Read the previous IP address from file
source $IP_FILE
echo "Old IP:" $OLD_IP
# Compare the new to the old IP
if [ "$IPADDRESS" != "$OLD_IP" ]
then
    echo "New IP address detected: $IPADDRESS"
    # Write new address to file
    `echo "OLD_IP=$IPADDRESS" > $IP_FILE`

    # FTP File to the appropriate places
    # Store it locally as well
    ncftpput -u user -p pass webspace.co.uk /remotefiletostorein/ /local/file/tostore.php

fi
```

Please be aware I have no idea about the security risks of doing this, for now it does not matter but please. Dont use this unless you know what your doing, I take no responsibility for this being insecure lol.

It does however give you a backup solution to dynamic hosting etc.